# How to change character_set_server in Amazon's Aurora DB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

Currently using Amazon's Aurora DB and in our Jira we are seeing some names with question marks (???) due to their characters.

After further looking into this it seems that I need to change the `character_set_server` from `latin1` to `utf8`.

In Aurora DB I looked in the parameter groups and cluster group settings but I don't see `character_set_server`, or anything similar.

Thank you.

Comment: I see it in cluster group settings. Open your cluster group settings for edit and enter "character" in the filter and you should see it along with some other character_set properties.

Comment: @MarkB You are correct.  I thought I was looking at the cluster group but I wasn't.  Thank you for that.  This is proof that I'm lacking some serious sleep.  ;)

Comment: you might want to use utf8mb4 instead of utf8 -- that way you have full utf8 support including 4-byte characters (emojis!)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As Mark B said, you can easily change it on "Parameter groups" page,

[image]

Open your cluster group settings for edit and enter "character_set_ser" in the filter and you should see it.

[image]

For more information read the following page:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-modify-parameter-group-values/

Comment: Thank you Reza for the screenshots!